# Why can't I create an AWS Lambda function in console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been trying to follow the tutorial at https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/helloworld to set up a custom alexa skill. I was able to compile the jar file fine. The problem is whenever I try to create my AWS lambda function I get this screen with no indication of what's wrong. Anyone seen this before?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Did you enter Java code into the console ?  Java is a compiled language, you can only upload class files (binaries) or JAR files, not source code.

Comment: I uploaded a compiled jar as the tutorial said to do.

Comment: Does your IAM user has enough permission to create lambda function ?  Did you retry (to eliminate the unlikely case of transient errors)

Comment: I tried again 2 weeks later and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow codes' instruction to deploy ?  In particular :

- Go to the the samples/ directory containing pom.xml, and run 'mvn
  assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package'. This
  will generate a zip file named
  "alexa-skills-kit-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" in the
  target directory.
- Select Code entry type as "Upload a .ZIP file" and then upload the
  "alexa-skills-kit-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" file from
  the build directory to Lambda

Comment: I ran the mvn command and it succeeded in generating the 2 jars, one with dependencies, one without. I used the alexa-skills-kit-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar to upload in the lambda console.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/helloworld and was able to successfully create a simple custom skill and was able to view my skill in Echo webpage.

My doubt is how do I invoke that skill?I don't have a echo with me

Comment: You can use https://echosim.io/ to test echo skills in your browser. Log in with the same amazon account you configured the skill with and you'll be able to test it even if not published.